# Save (possibly) duplicate Sequel Model instance

Tags: ruby, sequel

In Sequel, if you have a Model class called MyModel, you can do something like this:

```
#make MyModel instance
row = MyModel.new(column1, column2)
#save it to the database Sequel is connected to
row.save
```

However, "row.save" will fail if you're saving a duplicate primary key.

I'm looking for a method that will save a value to the database if the primary key is not duplicate and save nothing, without failing, otherwise.

I have looked through the [instance methods for Sequel Model](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html), but I haven't found what I'm looking for. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Sequel before, but you could always wrap the call to save with a begin/rescue block and just swallow the error without doing anything (you almost always want to do SOMETHING).

```
begin
  row = MyModel.new(col1, col2)
  row.save
rescue Sequel::DatabaseError => e
  # handle error here
end
```

Note: you might want something other than `DatabaseError` above.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel distinguishes newly created Model objects and Model objects fetched from the database -- even if they contain the same data. For example, if we get a record like this, saving to the database will succeed:

```
row = MyModel.where(:column1 => column1, :column2 => column2)
row.save
#save succeeds
```

If we make a new object with the same values and save it to the database, the save will fail:

```
row = MyModel.new(column1, column2)
row.save
#save returns duplicate primary key error
```

To update a value in the database without getting a duplicate primary key error, fetch the record with the relevant primary key (if it exists), modify it, and then save it.